# Can a fragment's onAttach be called before the Activity's onCreate has finished?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am experiencing a very rare (1 in a few thousand sessions) crash which I am trying to track down. I have an Activity which, during it's onCreate override, it creates some fragments but doesn't show or attach any of them:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mainMenuFragment = new MainMenuFragment();
    locationFragment = new LocationFragment();

    mainPresenter = new MainPresenter(this);
}
```

In this code I also create a "MainPresenter" which comes from a library which contains all our business logic. The presenter is used from the onAttach method of the fragments:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity) activity;
    mainPresenter = mainActivity.getMainPresenter();
    mainPresenter.refreshUI();
}
```

The issue is, that very rarely I am getting a null ptr exception in the onAttach. Is it possible that in some rare cases the fragment's onAttach is being executed before the Activities' onCreate has finished (i.e. mainPresenter is null)?

**Update**

Here is part of the callstack leading up to the crash, in case it is helpful:

```
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3253)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3349)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:5383)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200 (ActivityThread.java:221)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1800)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:158)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7225)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1230)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: I ran into this exact issue this week. I found that it was more common if I relaunched the app after having terminated it in the background via Android Studio's Android Monitor tab. If you need a reliable reproduction for testing, that might be useful.

Comment: @stkent - thanks, I'll give that a try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. See the documentation at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle). Fragment.onAttach happens before Fragment.onCreate and if the documentation for onCreate says that the activity can still be in the process of being created during this lifecycle method, then that means that it definitely can be under construction in onAttach, which happens before onCreate.

As to your specific scenario, if that is your entire onCreate of the activity, then those fragments are not hooked into the application at all; they have not been added via the fragment manager. They are only instantiated and cannot have Android lifecycle calls yet. I assume that there is something more complex going on and that fragments are being re-added after a configuration change or something when you get the crash.

Comment: Hi, yes that is the entire of my onCreate, and you have hit on the point of the question - I have seen that documentation that you have linked however the point is that these fragments haven't been added to the fragment manager yet, so as you say, something more complex seems to be happening, and I was searching for an answer as to what that may be.

Comment: I have updated the question with part of the call stack, in case that offers insight into the strange issue.

Comment: Since handleRelaunchActivity is in that stack, it is likely during a configuration change. The fragments that were attached before the configuration change are being reattached to the activity (by the fragment manager) before the activity has been created. You can call getActivity() and cast it to MainActivity in onActivityCreated().

Comment: I don't think your suggestion of doing the UI update onActivityCreated is going to work - it looks as though the Activity itself is recreated from time to time. I guess I will need to move the main presenter into a static instance so it doesn't get recreated as well (the business logic doesn't support having multiple instances all over the place)

Comment: Why would that not work? How familiar are you with how configuration changes affect an app? Also I would not make the presenter a static instance since you are passing the activity as a reference to the presenter. That would be a memory leak. You can check if the savedInstanceState is null in your onCreate of the activity to know if you need to re instantiate those fragments or if you need to grab them from the fragment manager.

Comment: The problem is fairly simple - the business logic library is designed to be created once, and only once. As you see, I was creating it in the Activity onCreate. However sometimes the Activity is recreated during the runtime of the process, resulting in an additional presenter being created. This is causing problems. This isn't some simple app that can store all it's state in a Bundle. The ideal solution would be to prevent the fragment manager from ever recreating fragments.

Comment: See if the retained fragment pattern solves your problem. http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html

Answer (score 0):

You may want to change your Activity#onCreate declaration to:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mainMenuFragment = new MainMenuFragment();

    locationFragment = new LocationFragment();

    mainPresenter = new MainPresenter(this);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

This is because **super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)** triggers the (re)attachment of the activity fragments and the system does this by calling **Fragment.onAttach()**.

However, in your case, mainPresenter ought to have been instantiated/initialized because it's needed in Fragment.onAttach, but it isn't so [yet] because it's below **super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)** which is currently in execution.

Comment: I've learned a lot more about activities and fragments since I posted this question. I think your answer is wrong, although I do appreciate it. Google deliberately say to be careful not to confuse the fragment lifecycle with the activity one. The reality is that fragments, added to the fragment manager, can be created and attached before the activity onCreate is ever even called.

Comment: "The reality is that fragments, added to the fragment manager, can be created and attached before the activity onCreate is ever even called".....



I guess you're simply repeating my answer in your own words because it's exactly what I'm passing across in my answer.

Comment: I guess your answer is basically rephrasing the already long accepted accepted answer in a less clear way.